# Chosen.js doesn't work well with Angular directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-chosen

I created a plunker code for this question here http://plnkr.co/edit/mTaRPoAsQQQ6OSEQLS3a?p=preview

This is the HTML code of the list

```
<select ng-model="modSelectedState" id="inputLocation-" name="filter_location"    
     class="location" ng-options="state as state.full_name for state in states" 
     chosen="states">
<option value="">State</option>
```

As you can see i created a directive and named it "chosen", here is the code:

```
app.directive('chosen', function ($http) {
var linker = function (scope, element, attr) {
    scope.$watch(scope.states, function (oldVal, newVal) {
        element.trigger('liszt:updated');
    });
    scope.$watch(attr.ngModel, function () {
        element.trigger('liszt:updated');
    });
    element.chosen({disable_search_threshold: 20});
};

return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: linker
}
});
```

Please note that I am using the older version of 'chosen" which requires 'liszt:updated' instead of 'chosen:updated'

I know that the states are being populated since when I inspect the code, I can see them in the original SELECT. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you notice you have an error on the console? It is saying Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [ngModel, ngModel] asking for 'ngModel' controller on: <select ng-model="modSelectedState ngModel" ng-options="item.item_value as item.item_name for item in items" items="states" default-value="'Select State...'">

Comment: @WebDever Yes. It is related to second directive. I have removed it to avoid confusion.The directive is still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the $watch on the directive to the name of the variable on the scope that you need to monitor. What was happening was that the watch was running the 'trigger' before the list had elements.

I put some $logs so you can check

http://plnkr.co/edit/mR8WhwvJiDZMG7Nlursg?p=preview

```
scope.$watch('states', function (newVal, oldVal) {
    element.trigger('liszt:updated');
    $log.info('trigger');            
});
```

Comment: By the way, please note that there is already a chosen directive written in angular https://github.com/localytics/angular-chosen/blob/master/chosen.js

Comment: is I am aware of this directive however I cannot use it. I am using a template which uses a different chosen version. The suggested version is different and causes to lose the original design .

Comment: thank you it works like magic now. For general purposes i changes 'states' to 'attr.chosen' and added 'chosen="states"'in the HTML.